# Como capturar um número em uma string usando expressões regulares (ou método similar) em Python?

Tags: python, regex

Eu gostaria de saber como posso selecionar uma parte específica do meu texto considerando que essa parte é referente a um valor que pode mudar. Por exemplo, a string:

```
#   44,739 % of all cache refs
```

Gostaria de extrair apenas o valor `44,739`. Só que esse valor pode ser modificado em outra linha, então não daria pra colocar como valor padrão da minha expressão, o que eu queria mesmo é selecionar o texto entre os caracteres `#` e `%`. Tem como?

Comment: Editei a pergunta e reparei que, entre o `#` e o número, existem três caracteres de espaço (ao invés do único caractere que estava sendo mostrado pelo HTML renderizado). São três espaços mesmo?

Comment: @Miguel, reverti porque os três espaços estavam no [texto original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/faf6b81f-5c42-4b94-b812-111c6432951e/view-source).

Comment: @LuizFelipe peço desculpa então, era capaz de jurar que tinha copiado por completo e um só espaço. Vou ajustar

Comment: @Miguel, sim, o HTML original só estava renderizando um espaço (é o comportamento esperado do HTML). No entanto, não sei se realmente era para ter três espaços. Por isso deixei o [primeiro comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/486248/como-capturar-um-n%c3%bamero-em-uma-string-usando-express%c3%b5es-regulares-ou-m%c3%a9todo-sim?noredirect=1#comment907130_486248). Vamos ver o que o AP nos diz.

Comment: Pois é verdade @LuizFelipe, html foi tramado, obgado pelo aviso

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se a ideia é pegar **somente** os números que estão entre `#` e `%`, então faça:

```
import re
texto = "# 44,739 % of all cache refs 12,345 lorem ipsum # 98,736 % etc 45,678 blablbla"
r = re.compile(r'#\s*(\d+,\d+)\s*%')
for n in r.findall(texto):
    print(n)
```

No caso, a regex pegará somente `44,739` e `98,736`. Os demais números serão ignorados, pois não estão entre `#` e `%`. Lembrando que antes e depois do número tem `\s*`, que indica zero ou mais espaços.

Mas se a ideia é pegar todos os números, independente do que tem antes ou depois, aí bastaria fazer `re.compile('\d+,\d+')`.

Também não ficou claro se o número sempre tem "dígitos, vírgula, dígitos". Se os dígitos depois da vírgula forem opcionais, pode trocar para `re.compile(r'#\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s*%')`.

Um detalhe importante é que o trecho que tem o número fica entre parênteses para formar um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Fiz isso porque quando a regex tem grupos de captura, [`findall` retorna somente o conteúdo dos grupos](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall).
E é por isso que na opção com a vírgula opcional eu uso `(?:`, pois isso forma um [grupo de não-captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) (asim o conteúdo deste não é retornado separadamente por `findall`).

---

[Uma das respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/486250/112052) usou `[\d\,\d]+`, mas isso pode dar falsos positivos, pois esta regex também pega somente a vírgula. Por exemplo:

```
print(re.findall(r'[\d\,\d]+', 'a, b, 10, d')) # [',', ',', '10,']
```

O resultado terá as 2 vírgulas depois do "a" e do "b", além de `10,`. Já usando as opções acima, esse problema não ocorre. A saber, isso ocorre porque os colchetes definem uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), então `[\d,\d]` significa "um `\d` (dígito), **ou** uma vírgula, **ou** um `\d`" (apenas um deles, e sim, o `\d` é redundante neste caso), por isso esta regex pega somente uma vírgula sozinha (e pegaria também várias, como `,,,,,`).

---

#### Sem regex

Mas se você "sabe" que só tem uma ocorrência do número (ou só quer a primeira), pode fazer sem regex:

```
try:
    texto = "# 44,739 % of all cache refs"
    start = texto.index('#') + 1
    end = texto.index('%', start + 1)
    possivel_numero = texto[start:end].strip()
    numero = float(possivel_numero.replace(',', '.'))
    print(numero)
except ValueError:
    print('não tem um número ou não tem os caracteres # ou %')
```

Eu uso [`index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) para obter as posições do `#` e `%`, e uso um *slice* (`[start:end]`) para obter o trecho entre essas posições. E depois tento converter para número (tive que trocar a vírgula por ponto, já que `float` reconhece somente o ponto como separador decimal - mas caso o número use notação americana, na qual a vírgula separa os milhares, então faça `replace(',', '')`).

Se a conversão para número falhar, ou não tiver um dos caracteres indicados (`#` ou `%`), será lançado um `ValueError`.

---

Ou, se quiser encontrar todas as ocorrências:

```
texto = "# 44,739 % of all cache refs 12,345 lorem ipsum # 98,736 % etc 45,678 blablbla # abc %"
start = end = 0
while True:
    start = texto.find('#', end)
    if start == -1:
        print('Não tem mais nenhum #')
        break
    end = texto.find('%', start + 1)
    if end == -1:
        print('Não tem mais nenhum %')
        break
    possivel_numero = texto[start + 1:end].strip()
    try:
        numero = float(possivel_numero.replace(',', '.'))
        print(numero)
    except ValueError:
        print('não é um número')
```

Outra opção é usar [`partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
texto = "#    44,739   % of all cache refs 12,345 lorem ipsum # 98,736 % etc 45,678 blablbla # abc %"
tmp = texto
while True:
    _, _, tmp = tmp.partition('#')
    if not tmp: # não tem mais #
        break
    possivel_numero, sep, tmp = tmp.partition('%')
    if not sep: # não tem mais %
        break
    try:
        numero = float(possivel_numero.replace(',', '.').strip())
        print(numero)
    except ValueError:
        print('não é um número')
```

Basicamente, `partition` retorna uma tupla contendo as partes antes e depois do separador, além do próprio. Se não houver mais como separar, retorna strings vazias.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar a seguinte expressão regular:

```
r"(\d+,\d+)"
```

<sup>Veja no [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5O5syZ/4).</sup>

Ela irá selecionar qualquer número contido na string (sendo `,` o separador decimal). Se for possível aparecer números em outras partes da string, você pode limitar a expressão para só procurar por números entre `#`  (no começo da string) e  `%` (após o número). Fica assim:

```
r"^# (\d+,\d+) %"
```

<sup>Veja no [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5O5syZ/3).</sup>

Note que, nas duas expressões regulares, existem grupos de captura para que possamos "extrair" o número em eventual *match*. Veja um exemplo funcional:

```
import re

data = '# 44,739 % of all cache refs'

match = re.search(r"^# (\d+,\d+) %", data)

# Pega o primeiro grupo de captura e imprime:
num_str = match.group(1)
print(num_str)
```

Mas note que, como padrão da string é evidentemente simples e, nesse caso, expressão regular pode não ser necessário. A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/486250/69296) provê uma alternativa.

Só como adendo, se precisar de fazer uso do número contido na string, precisará converter o separador decimal de vírgula para ponto antes de realizar o *parse*. Exemplo:

```
num = float(num_str.replace(',', '.'))
```